# Does Log4J exist for Scala 3?

Tags: java, scala, log4j

When I go to the [mvn site](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api-scala) I only see 2.13 in supported versions. This seems echoed in the [docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/scala/index.html).

> Log4j Scala API is a Scala logging facade based on Log4j 2. Support for Scala versions 2.10, 2.11, and 2.12 is provided, and experimental support for pre-release versions of 2.13 is also provided.

So can I use the 2.13 version with 3? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Use 2.13 dependency with Scala 3, should work if it doesn't use any of incompatible features - see https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/migration/compatibility-classpath.html

Comment: Can you structure this into an answer for others? Thank you so much this was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Do you really want to use a library wrapper that has not been updated for 2 years? Given the recent log4j vulnerabilities, I wouldn't. Also considering the docs talks about "experimental 2.13 versions" when today 2.13 has been here for a while.

Comment: Personally, I'd use scala-logging (backed by Slf4)j with Logback, but I don't know OPs use cases.

Answer (score 3):

Virtually every 2.13 library which isn't relying on macros, or some features dropped in 3, is usable from Scala 3 from the day 1.

You just need to configure it in sbt as

```
// settings for Scala 3 project
libraryDependencies += ("organization" %% "library" % "version").cross(CrossVersion.for3Use2_13)
```

this `.cross(CrossVersion.for3Use2_13)` will make sbt use 2.13 version instead of 3 version which might be not available (Log4j Scala API isn't).

Details and limitations of this gradual migration from 2.13 to 3 are described [in the documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/migration/compatibility-classpath.html).